# How difficult is it act as a domain reseller from with a social network app?

Tags: php, dns, social-networking

I'm thinking of creating a social network for a niche hobbyist network and I know there's an appetite for people to have their own unique domain name (www.myfoowebsite.com) as opposed to whatever their unique url is on my platform of choice (www.opensourcesocial/124/ghyu.php)

I guess the best comparision is http://flavours.me/ which allows you to hook up your own domain..

How do I approach this? i know people will need to point their nameservers towards my app but I'm rather at a loss as to what I would need to do my end..

Any guidance appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to register domains (so called `top level domains` - .at, .de, .com, .org ...?)?
You need:

- a **nameserver** (or someone who provides name service to you) - the dns server is responsible for e.g. yourdomain.com / you configure your nameserver appropriately for *yourdomain.com* (with all needed records -> `SOA, MX, A, AAAA (if your server is IPv6 capable), NS ...` - important for you are at the end the `A` or/and `AAAA` records which need to contain the IP of your server as content:
  for example you need an `A record` for `www.yourdomain.com` with content of your servers IPv4 address (e.g.) `127.0.0.1` and an `AAAA record` with content of your servers IPv6 address (e.g. - if possible)  `::1`
- a **registrar** - someone who actually is "allowed" to register tlds (top level domains) or has interfaces to one. Here you have to provide the details of the person registering a domain and here you set the nameservers IP address and its hostname
- the **vhosts** on your server for "controlling" the domains ;-) (setting document root, special php settings ...)

That's explained very basically - you need some knowhow (or someone who has some!) to do that appropriately and securely!

Answer (score 0):

On your end, you'd set your site as default for any domainname for the ip (usually in Apache, if you use that, with an `ServerAlias *` directive (see [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#serveralias)).

Then, all you have to do is to read the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable in PHP, and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need a dedicated server to do this (in this case see @Wrikken's answer on how), or a nice hosting provider who agrees to register external domains with your hosting package's server. Not everyone does that.

Once that has been done, the PHP `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` variable will give you the domain name the page was requested under.

Comment: Not necessarily a *'nice'* hosting-provider, more like *'any decent'* hosting provider IMHO (as long as you've got your own IP-address of course :) ). Then again, it's been a long time since I've used anything with less control then a VPS...

Comment: @Wrikken yeah, true. :) I like shared/managed hosting for the ease of mind it provides - no server maintenance work / dealing with updates /  hotfixes / zero-day exploits etc. but obviously, for a service like what the OP is planning to do, full control over the server may be necessary.

Comment: Hehe, yeah, it really helps if you can offload that maintenance work on somebody else :D